# Django Rest Framework Serializer Relations: How to get list of all child objects in parent's serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and have just started building an API. I have two models, a child model connected to a parent model with a foreign key. Here is the simplified version of the model I have:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

To create serializers, I followed the [DRF Serializer Relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) and I've created them as the following:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    parent_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Parent.objects.all(),source='parent.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('url','id','child_name','parent_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        subject = Child.objects.create(parent=validated_data['parent']['id'], child_name=validated_data['child_name'])

        return child


class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('url','id','name','children')
```

I'm trying to get the list of all children in parent's serializer. What I want is to be able to get a response like this:

```
{
    'url': 'https://dummyapidomain.com/parents/1/',  
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Dummy Parent Name',
    'cildren': [
        {'id': 1, 'child_name': 'Dummy Children I'},
        {'id': 2, 'child_name': 'Dummy Children II'},
        {'id': 3, 'child_name': 'Dummy Children III'},
        ...
    ],
}
```

I wasn't expecting this to work since there is no link between Parent and Child in the Parent model, [but it is the suggested way to do it in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), and it didn't work.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `children` on serializer `ParentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Parent` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'children'.
```

I think it's perfectly reasonable, but I couldn't understand what I'm missing here.

How can I get the list of all children in parent's serializer?

Comment: I believe the related name for a backwards relation defaults to `{field_name}_set`, so in this case `children_set`. You should be able to just replace `children` with `children_set` in your `ParentSerializer`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think your problem is you forgot to add a **related_name** for your Children model. I would have the models like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')  # <--- Add related_name
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

And I think with this change you will solve the error your getting

Answer (score 15):

You can implement this in two way:

1. With `SerializerMethodField` :
   your code became like this:

   ```
   class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        children_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_get_children')

        def _get_children(self, obj):
            serializer = ChildSerializer(obj.child_list(), many=True)
            return serializer.data

       class Meta:
           model = Course
           fields = ('url','id','name','children_list')
   ```
2. Every field could be attribute of model or a method, so you can define a get_children_list method in `Parent` model, then call it in list of fields of `ParentSerializer`:

   ```
   class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

       class Meta:
            model = Course
            fields = ('url','id','name','get_children_list')
   ```

Note: You need to inherits from `serializers.ModelSerializer` in this scenario

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the first one, I get the same error: **'Parent' object has no attribute 'child_list'**.

Comment: I said, child_list is a method in your Parent class which returns list of children

Comment: You can get the set of children there also, by obj.children_set.all()